# Finite time strategy: search and destroy

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

A boat, which represented by a point, moves in uniform motion along the real line $\mathbb{R}$. At any
moment, the boat's position and speed are not known. The only information available is :

(i) its position at time $t = 0$ is an integer $x$.

(ii) the speed (measured per minute) is an integer $v$.

Every minute from $t = 0$, we drop a missile on a lattice point (an integer coordinate). If the boat is there, it sinks and we have won.

Is there a strategy to guarantee the sinking of the ship in finite time?

Comment: If the boat's speed is unbounded, it seems quite obviously impossible. Is there some context to the problem? Are your tags to be taken as "hints"?

Comment: The boat's speed is a finite integer. Do you mean there is no strategy? I do not know the answer but there is definitely a nice answer

Comment: Do you drop the missile always on the same lattice point? Or on a random point? Or is the point a function of t?

Comment: you can choose where to drop it, and the question is likely wanting you to think of that dropping as a function of t. So basically, for any n(t) can we choose an x(t) s.t. n(t) is not equal to x(t) for all t? Or perhaps can we show that for all linear x(t), there exists an n(t) s.t. x=n at some t. x(t) is clearly x(0)+vt

Comment: @minusatwelfth: I understand now -- from your second sentence I thought the boat's position *and* speed were variable. Maybe you should clarify this in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t)\colon \mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^2$ be surjective.

Represent the boat's starting position and velocity as $(x,v)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Strategy: At time $t$, we guess the boat's starting position and velocity coordinate are $f(t)$. Then we drop a missile on the position where that would mean the boat is currently (in particular we drop the missile at $x+vt$).

Since $f(t)$ is surjective, $f(t)=(x,v)$ is satisfied for some finite $t$, and we have victory.

Comment: I don't understand the strategy, is f the missile function? and f(t)=x+vt? v is constant by the way

Comment: $f(t)=(x,v)$ for some t but the boat won't necessarily be there at the same t

Comment: @minusatwelfth $f(t)$ is not the missile function. It is an arbitrary function which maps the positive integers to the integers in a plane, with the constraint that $f(t)=(a,b)$ has a solution for every integer pair $(a,b)$.

Comment: @minusatwelfth The idea is you are guaranteed to guess the starting position and velocity eventually. When you have done that, you figure out where the boat is given the starting position and velocity and time, and drop a missile in the appropriate location.

Comment: Nice, I think I get it